# Setting Background Image Programmatically In A Xib

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview, uicontrol

I have a XIB file with `UIControl` and `UIScrollView` elements inside of it. I would like to add a background image to the view. I tried adding an ImageView in IB but I could not get it to be present as a background and it obscured the control elements. Sending a `sendViewBack` message doesn't seem to do anything either.

When I create a UIImageView programmatically, it doesn't show up.

Below is the code I attempted:

Programmatic Creation

```
UIImage *imageBackground = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"globalbackground"];

UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageBackground];

[[self view] addSubview:backgroundView];

[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
```

Dealing with the NIB file

```
[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

where background is an `IBOutlet` declared in the header file and connected to the NIB's image view in IB.

Is there a step I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the frame and dont use `sendSubviewToBack:`. If you are working with UIImageViews you have to use `[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];`

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageBackground"]];
backgroundView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[[self view] addSubview:backgroundView];
```

hope this was the deal.

Comment: if there are other UI components, make sure to use insertSubView like below : [self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];

Answer (score 5):

- Don't add the image view as a subview of the scroll view, it needs to be a separate view at the top level of the hierarchy, *then* sent to the back of the Z-order.
- You will need to set the background of your scroll view to `[UIColor clearColor]`, and ensure that the scroll view is not marked as opaque. You can do this in code or in interface builder.
- Don't use `imageWithContentsOfFile` and then just pass it a filename with no extension (I'm assuming .png) - this is probably returning `nil`. Use `imageNamed:` instead (you don't supply an extension in that case, iOS4 and above)

Depending on the nature of your image, you can also generate a colour with it and use *that* as the background colour of your scroll view. I'm assuming self.view is the scroll view:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"globalBackground"]];
```